# Python - addition to an existing row of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to add or subtract to an existing dataframe?

For example, given the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
Apple= pd.DataFrame({'Product':['MacBook', 'iPhone', 'iPad', 'Apple Watch'],
                        'Inventory':['999', '333', '666', '190']})
```

Is there a way to add 150 to an existing inventory so that the number of Apple Watches is 340?

Comment: `Apple.loc[Apple.Product.eq('Apple Watch'), 'Inventory'] += 150`

Comment: @VanPeer you should avoid that, as it's chained indexing, which is discouraged in `pandas`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `loc` along with a boolean selection to update the column:

```
Apple.loc[Apple.Product.eq('Apple Watch'), 'Inventory'] += 150
```

```
       Product  Inventory
0      MacBook        999
1       iPhone        333
2         iPad        666
3  Apple Watch        340
```

In the example you've provided in your question, `Inventory` contains strings.  If this is the same in your actual data, you need to cast to `int` first:

```
Apple.Inventory = Apple.Inventory.astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert your series of strings to an `int` series:

```
df['Inventory'] = df['Inventory'].astype(int)
```

You can then use `pd.DataFrame.loc`:

```
df.loc[df['Product'] == 'Apple Watch', 'Inventory'] += 150
```

Alternatively, you can make `Product` your index and then update:

```
df = df.set_index('Product')
df.loc['Apple Watch', 'Inventory'] += 150
```

Using either method, if you have multiple products with the same name, their inventory will *each* be increased by 150.

Answer (score 0):

if you define your items as int , you can do it this way:

```
import pandas as pd
Apple= pd.DataFrame({'Product':['MacBook', 'iPhone', 'iPad', 'Apple Watch'],
                        'Inventory':['999', '333', '666', 190]})

Apple.Inventory[Apple.Product == 'Apple Watch'] += 150
print(Apple)
```